# Static route produces host unreachable error

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing, ping

I have a linux server with three interfaces - one for net, two internal, below are shown the internal ones:

> eth1
>             inet addr:192.168.10.253
>             Bcast:192.168.255.255
>             Mask:255.255.0.0
>
> eth2
>             inet addr:10.10.10.253
>             Bcast:10.10.10.255
>             Mask:255.255.255.0

Have one internal work machine with gate 192.168.10.253 and ip from that subnet and other with gate 10.10.10.253 and ip from its subnet. I need to be able to have access between those machines.

On the linux box I have the following routing table:

```
default via * dev eth0
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.10.253
* dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src *
192.168.10.0/16 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.253
```

I added a static route:

> route add -net 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.10.253

and the result

> 10.10.10.0/24 via 192.168.10.253 dev eth1  scope link

but when I try to ping from eth1 an up and running interface 10.10.10.2 it always gives destination host unreachable. What am I missing as configuration?

The basic setup is shown here:

[image]

When I ping from eth1

```
ping 10.10.10.2 -I eth1
PING 10.10.10.2 (10.10.10.2) from 192.168.10.253 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.10.253 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

and when I ping from eth2:

```
ping 10.10.10.2 -I eth2
PING 10.10.10.2 (10.10.10.2) from 10.10.10.253 eth2: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.547 ms
```

Comment: So you want traffic to 10.10.10.0/24 to got out of eth1 via gateway 192.168.10.253. Is that correct? That's what you've said and what your routing table implies. What then, is the point of the eth2 connection?

Comment: licensing demand unfortunately..it needs primary address from that range, for evaluation purposes

Comment: So is there a route from 192.168.10.253 to the 10.10.10.0/24 subnet? From the OP: "...other with gate 10.10.10.253 and ip from its subnet." so it sounds like there isn't.

Comment: I need to add that with ip rule?

Comment: Depends on what device that gateway is. Is there even a physical connection from that gateway device to the 10.10.10.0/24 subnet. Might help if you can post a network diagram.

Comment: (1) I’m having some trouble visualizing your setup.  Could you add an ASCII-art diagram of your network?  Or at least list, all in one place, all the machine that you are mentioning in your question? (2) Also, show more of the commands you used, and not just their output. (3) Is the 192.168.0.0/16 generally working OK?  That’s an unusual configuration.

Comment: thank you, both. I updated the description and added asciiflow diagram.

Comment: (4) You indicate that your Linux box already had a route `10.10.10.0/24 via 192.168.0.253` before you added the `10.10.10.0/24 via 192.168.10.253` route.  Can you explain that?  (5) Can you explain why ``ping`` thinks `10.10.10.2` is `1.1.1.1`?  (6) Your diagram indicates that machine #1 has address 192.168.10.253.  I presume that this is just a typo. (7) When I suggested ASCII art, my thought was that you would just post the ASCII in your question, rather than converting it into a PNG and uploading it.  Oh well, do whatever is more convenient for you.

Comment: sorry Scott, stupid clipboard, cause I have couple of environments which I am trying to configure. I edited the post correctly.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It’s good that the above comment wasn’t important, because I almost never saw it.  When you write a comment to a specific person, you should put ‘@’ followed by their name into the comment; for example, “@Scott”, or see Darren’s comment to you below his answer. You are being notified about this comment because it’s under your question.

Comment: Pls take a look at my answer too, since it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per your network diagram, there is no physical link from the `192.168.10.253` device to the `10.10.10.0/24` network so there is no way on Earth you should expect to get a response when you ping `10.10.10.2` out of `eth1`. The only way to ping `10.10.10.2` successfully is for the ping request to go out of `eth2`.

If you really need this to work, the solution is to connect `192.168.10.253` to `10.10.10.2` and create a route. How you do this depends on the nature of the two boxes. If they're servers they might have a second network port you can connect up (and configure appropriately). If they don't have a second network interface then you are probably out of luck without completely changing your network configuration. My suggestion, as you are probably in a bit of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), is to post a new question describing *what you need to achieve*, not how you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks Darren, should we simply re-use this thread rather than start a new one.

Comment: @modzozo. No, that's not how this site works, it's not a forum. This is one question. If you want to ask something else, ask a new question (although by all means link to this one).

Answer (score 0):

You **do not** need another route to allow users of the private subnets to communicate. You only need the following commands:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

The first two commands tell the firewall to allow traffic to flow between the two private subnets, and the third command does the same at the kernel level. You need both.

That's all.

Comment: OK, this has allowed traffic to pass across the interfaces, but the OP is specifically trying to ping the 10... subnet via the 192... device on eth1. How does this allow them to do that? The OP hasn’t actually explained why they need to do this or what they are trying to achieve.